# How to fix spatial reference error on CopyFeatures ArcGIS tool?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

When I run the CopyFeatures tool to copy features from an ArcSDE geodatabase to another empty ArcSDE geodatabase (no features, no tables), I get the following result:

[image]

The error message is about the spatial reference of the output feature class. The output is created by the tool itself. Why wouldn't it set the correct spatial reference?

Do you have any hint on how fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An error message in your screenshot is **[000372 and documented](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00vp00000026000372)**.

I recommend that you try the solution suggested there:

> **Description**
>
> The tool failed while trying to set the spatial grid indexes for the
>   output.
>
> **Solution**
>
> You can get an estimate for an appropriate spatial grid index by using
>   [CalculateDefaultGridIndex](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002n000000) on the input dataset. Then temporarily set
>   the [SpatialGrid1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w00000019000000) and, as necessary, SpatialGrid2 and SpatialGrid3
>   environments. This will help provide indexes that are appropriate when
>   running the tool. Reset the environments to their previous setting
>   when finished.

This sounds to me like it could fit your description.

The other error showing in your screenshot is **[000224 and also documented](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/000224_Cannot_insert_features/00vp0000000n000224/)**.  Its advice is:

> **Description**
>
> The tool failed to write records to the output feature class or table.
>   This error is typically the result of mismatched field definitions
>   between incoming features and the output feature class or table.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Where possible, adjust the input field properties to be consistent
>   with the expected output field properties.

This seems unlikely to be the cause.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try that.

What I don't understand is why do I have to do anything for the output? It's created by the tool so it should be correctly set up.

Why should I modify the grids of the input? I don't have any problem with the input. I don't want to change it.

Comment: Thanks. The first solution worked. I have no more errors.